# SwiftUI: trigger redraw when NSManagedObject (not part of fetch request) bool property changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following @SectionedFetchRequest installed on my SwiftUI view:

```
@SectionedFetchRequest(entity: Car.entity(),
                       sectionIdentifier: \.dealer.name,
                       sortDescriptors: [
                        NSSortDescriptor(key: "\(#keyPath(Car.dealer.name))", ascending: true),
                        NSSortDescriptor(key: "\(#keyPath(Car.milage))", ascending: true),
                       ]
                       , predicate: nil,
                       animation: .default)
var carsResult: SectionedFetchResults<String, Car>
```

In the view, I have this:

```
LazyVStack {
                                    
    ForEach(carsResult) { section in
                        
        if let dealer = section.first?.dealer {
                            
            Section(header:  DealerSHView(dealer: dealer)) {

                if dealer.isOpen {
                     ForEach(section) { channel in
                         ....
                     }
                } else {
                     ....
                }

            }
                            
        }
                        
    }
}
```

When a button is pressed on the `DealerSHView`, the dealer.isOpen boolean is toggled.
`Dealer` is a NSManagedObject, like `Car` is.

Problem:
the view does not update, specifically this part:

```
            if dealer.isOpen {
                 ForEach(section) { channel in
                     ....
                 }
            } else {
                 ....
            }
```

has no effect, it just runs the case that is detected at first render, but not when `isOpen` changes and it's saved to disk via core data save.

**Question**:
How can I get the view to react and redraw when `isOpen` changes?

Comment: All CoreData objects are `ObservableObject`s you have to wrap each object with `@ObservedObject` to see the change

Comment: yes, so, I am not sure how to wrap the deal entities as I use them from the carsResult...

Comment: Put the code in another view. A subiré that has the wrapper as a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it all into a sub-View and use `@ObservedObject` like this:

```
struct DealerSection : View {
    @ObservedObject var dealer: Dealer // body will be called when dealer changes.

    var body: some View {
        Section(header:  DealerSHView(dealer: dealer)) {

            if dealer.isOpen {
                 ForEach(section) { channel in
                     ....
                 }
            } else {
                 ....
            }

         }
    }
```

Then in your parent View's body it's just:

```
ForEach(carsResult) { section in
                        
        if let dealer = section.first?.dealer {
                            
            DealerSection(dealer: dealer)
                            
        }
                        
    }
```